# How do I enable Firebug 1.4 only for specific domains?

Tags: firefox, firebug

Firebug 1.4 has an option to enable or disable it for *all* pages.  However, I (usually) only want to temporarily enable it for just one domain.  In earlier versions, this was trivial, but I can't find anyway to do it in 1.4.

(To give context, I typically have several windows open with several tabs each.  Many of the sites open are ajax heavy (e.g., gmail or Google docs) which don't play nicely w/ Firebug.  So if I want to quickly see, say an HTTP response code, for a particular site, I have to enable Firebug for all sites making my browser crawl.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike previous versions of firebug, if you have it closed and don't have it set to "On for all web pages" it's actually not running. It's *only* on when you open up the panel and are actively using it.

The solution: just open it on the domains you want to use it on. It does a pretty good job of remembering (at least for me).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't select either "Off for all web pages" or "On for all web pages", you can open Firebug from domain to domain by left-clicking on the icon.  To close it in a particular domain, hit the off button in the top-right corner.  If you already have one of the global options selected, just select that one and it will deselect it.

Edit: for further description of how this should be:
If you right-click on the firebug icon in the FF status bar, you will see "Off/On for All Web Pages".  You don't want either of those checked.  If one is checked, click it and it will be unchecked.

Then by default the firebug icon should be greyed out and the panel down for all web pages.  If you want to open the panel on one page, click on the icon.  It should turn coloured and open the panel.  If you want to turn firebug off for a web site, click the "off" button in the top right of the panel.